# Multiple buttons on a form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create a page that has multiple buttons. For example a page with two text fields and four buttons labeled add, subtract, multiply and divide. Clicking on one of the buttons would cause the appropriate action on the two fields and the return the answer in another text box.

Anyone have any ideas on how I can do this. I only know about forms that have one submit button. Am I missing some different way where I can just call back and get an answer then have it written to the page?

Comment: Are you asking to do this with WebForms or with MVC? You can this setup in many different ways depending on which pointn of view you're asking from.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this without problem. Be sure that all your buttons have an event handler. 
For example:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubtract" runat="server" Text="Subtract" onclick="btnSubtract_Click" />
```

and your code behind would have:

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Add code
}

protected void btnSubtract_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Subtract code
}
```

Remember also that asp pages do not remember state. If you are clicking a button and outputting the answer and the original numbers are lost, you will need to put them back onto the form. This is because the user's browser will loose this information when the page comes back from the server.